# Exercise - Reason program runs slow and how to fix it

Tags: java

I got this piece of code:

```
public class Fibonacci {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int SIZE;

    if (args.length == 0) {
        SIZE = 100;
    } else {
        SIZE = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    for (int n = 1; n <= SIZE; n++) {
        double timeStart = stopwatch.elapsedTime();
        long fiboNumber = fib(n);
        double timeEnd = stopwatch.elapsedTime();
        System.out.print(n + " " + fiboNumber + "\t");
        double lapTime = timeEnd - timeStart;
        System.out.printf(" (%.3f \t %.3f)\n", lapTime, timeEnd);
    }
}

public static long fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
}
```

The goal of this program is to modify it so the program runs smooth.
Now when the program is running the counter will go slow at around 40.
I just can't figure out why this is happening and how I can fix it so it runs smooth to 100.

Comment: You have to use the recursive function?

Comment: Why re-calculate something you've already calculated?  As you determine each element in the Fibonacci sequence, store them in an array.  So instead of re-calculating them every time, just refer to the ones you've already calculated.

Comment: You are basically printing the fibonacci series, There are other ways to do this in very less time! Here you are doing some things which you have already calculated so everytime time becomes almost double so its increasing with the power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its going slow at around 40 is that the fibonacci function is spending a lot of time trying to compute the integer. Instead of using a recursive implementation of fibonacci, use a dynamic programming implementation.